# Rails 4.0 has_many :through associations, how to pull fields via id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I am new to rails and been playing around with creating a web app for cooking, recipes, etc. to work through learning some new things. I have gotten a bit stuck on one particular aspect.

I have three tables set up to work together: lessons, preparations, and ingredients.

My models are set up like this:

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :preparations
  has_many :ingredients, through: :preparation
end

class Preparation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :lesson
  has_many :ingredients
end

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :preparation
  belongs_to :lessons, through: :preparation
end
```

In my lesson show view, I want to show the name of the ingredient. But I can only seem to get to the ingredient_id which is in the preparation table to link up with ingredients. So I can get the view to display a integer (the ingredient_id) but not the name. I've tried a bunch of things, but cannot seem to access the ingredients table.

Any help on how to get this configured correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: Your `has_many :through` should use `:preparations`, not `:preparation`. Assuming this is a typo, please show how you're attempting to access the ingredients for a given lesson; there's nothing wrong with the way your associations are laid out.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo, and there is an s on the through associations. right now I am using the following to pull info what I can `<% @lesson.preparations.each do |p| %> <%= p[:quantity] %> <%=  p[:unit].downcase %> <%=  p[:prep].downcase %> <%=  p[:ingredient_id] %>` but don't know how to get from the last part over to other fields in ingredients table.

Comment: `p.ingredient.name` will work (or `p.ingredient[:name]` I suppose, though using the accessor methods is the more typical way).

Comment: Still not working for me. I have tried the above and every configuration I can think of to access the name field in the ingredients table, and it will not display in the lesson view at all.